# Using R, drop columns with more than 20% 0s

Tags: r, filter, subset

I have a dataframe in R. For each entry I have 10 columns with values, and one last column indicating the group that entry belongs to (group A, group B, group C etc.)

What I need to do is:

1 ) Drop all columns where more than 20% of entries are equal to 0

and

2) Drop all columns where more than 20% of values are 0 in either of the groups. In other worse, I want to preserve only columns that have minumun 20% non zeros for each group indepedently.

Can you please help  :-s

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `colMeans` on a logical vector

```
df1[colMeans(df1 == 0)  < 0.2]
```

If it based on a 'group'

```
nm1 <- setdiff(names(df1), "group")
i1 <- !Reduce(`|`,  lapply(split(df1[nm1], df1$group), 
                 function(x) colMeans(x == 0) >= 0.2))
df1[c("group", names(which(i1)))]
```

---

Or using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   select_if(~ mean(. == 0) < 0.2)
```

With the grouping, it can be

```
df1 %>%
   group_by(group) %>% 
   summarise_at(vars(-group_cols()), ~ mean(.==0) >= 0.2) %>% 
   summarise_at(-1, any) %>%
   select_if(~ !.) %>%
   names %>% 
   select(df1, group, .)
```

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(group = rep(c("A", "B", "C"), each = 5),
   col1 = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 5, 3, 0, 0, 1:5), col2 = 1:15, col3 = c(0, 1:14) )
```

Comment: Thank you guys!!! That's awesome!